# How to add regex flags to atom editor search?

Tags: regex, atom-editor

I've tried wrapping my query with `/ query /gm` or `query/gm` but it doesn't seem to recognize the flags. What is the proper syntax to add refer flags in atom editor search? Or is this just related to not being able to search multiple lines?

Comment: Isn't that `(?m)query` ?

Comment: It seems to be telling me that's an invalid group since it includes it inside the forward slashes.

Comment: `m` modifier is on by default in Atom.